# How do I modify a sql file so that transactions are placed inside an EXEC statement using powershell and regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using Azure Pipelines to create Entity Framework migration scripts.

Generated scripts look like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20200806210137_FooBar')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'20200806210137_FooBar', N'3.1.6');
END;
```

I need everything between "BEGIN" and "END" to be enclosed in an `EXEC('{Transaction}')` statement. It should also escape single quotes.

The end result should look like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20200806210137_FooBar')
BEGIN
    EXEC('INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N''20200806210137_FooBar'', N''3.1.6');')
END;
```

How can I achieve this using Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$output = @'
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20200806210137_FooBar')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'20200806210137_FooBar', N'3.1.6');
END;
'@

$output -replace '(?s)(?<=BEGIN\r?\n)(\s+)(.+)(?=\r?\nEND)','$1EXEC(''$2'')'

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20200806210137_FooBar')
BEGIN
    EXEC('INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'20200806210137_FooBar', N'3.1.6');')
END;
```

**Edit**

Having "escape single quotes" click, this should work for that as well. You may need to tweak it.

```
$output -replace '''','''''' -replace '(?s)(?<=BEGIN\r?\n)(\s+)(.+)(?=\r?\nEND)','$1EXEC(''$2'')'
```